# CSS Element Transition on Hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

I am trying to replicate something like the expanding onhover menu at http://www.gk-films.com but in HTML5/CSS3 way. They have a small element absolutely positioned to the right of the window, which on hover expands to a full-width menu with options.

So far, I have tried both jQuery and browser-specific transition effects, but cannot come up with a solid working solution.

My ground work is such right now:
http://jsfiddle.net/z64vX/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#main">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


body { background: #bbb; }
nav { display: block }

nav { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 30%; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 40px; 
    z-index: 950; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9); 
    -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease, right 0.5s ease;
}
nav:hover { 
    right: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
}
nav ul { display: none; width: 100%; }
nav:hover ul { display: block; }
```

The problem is that the transition is not working properly for positioning and width of nav container (it just jumps to the end 'left' value).

Ideally, the menu elements will fade in after the expanding is done, so if you put in that part too it would be great.

Perhaps, it would be better to do via jQuery's animate function, but I did not want to create a mess with different code variations here.

---

After some fiddling I am actually getting somewhere with jQuery animate: http://jsfiddle.net/z64vX/6/

```
$(function(){
    var nav = $("nav"),
    navHeight = nav.height();

    nav.hover(
        function() {
            navOn();
        }, function() {
            navOff();
        }
    );

    var navOn = function(){
        nav.stop().animate({right: '0%', width: '100%', height: navHeight}, 1000, function() {
            $(this).find("ul").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    };

    var navOff = function(){
        nav.animate({right: '10%', width: '200px', height: '20px'}, 500).find("ul").fadeOut(100);
    };

    navOff();
});
```

Any thoughts on how bulletproof this is to use? Or if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this.

```
body { background: #bbb;text-align:center; }
nav { display: inline-block; }

nav { 
    top: 0; 
    text-align:left; 
    width: 40%; 
    height: 40px; 
    z-index: 950; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9); 
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
nav:hover { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}
nav ul { display: none; width: 100%; }
nav:hover ul { display: block; }
​
```

Comment: I understand that declaring the initial width as a percentage would work, but it has to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyfollahi/a8edq/) should help you.

```
body { background: #bbb; }
nav { display: block }

nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 950;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow:hidden;
}
nav:hover {

    width: 100%;
    right:0;
    height: 90px;
}
nav ul { display: none; width: 100%; padding:5px;}
nav:hover ul { display: block; }
```

But you can't set `height:auto;`